# How to express the curvature in polar coordinates with DSolveChangeVariables (or without it)?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

The curvature `k[x]` of a plane curve `y==y[x]` is given by

`k[x] == RealAbs[y''[x]]/(1 + y'[x]^2)^(3/2)`

(see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Curvature&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1) for info).
The above relation can be treated as an ODE in `y[x]` with a known `k[x]`. Is it possible to express that relation
in the polar coordinates, making use of  a new command in version 13.1 `DSolveChangeVariables`?
The documentation says about `"Cartesian" -> "Polar"` only for PDEs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done in two steps.

First,

```
DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][k[x] == RealAbs[y''[x]]/(1 + y'[x]^2)^(3/2), y,x],
 y, θ, x == r[θ]*Cos[θ]]
```

> `Inactive[DSolve][ k[Cos[θ] r[θ]] ==  RealAbs[(-(( Derivative[1][ y][θ] (-Cos[θ] r[θ] -  2 Sin[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ] +  Cos[θ] ( r^′′)[θ]))/(-r[θ] \ Sin[θ] + Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])^2) + ( y^′′)[θ]/(-r[θ] Sin[θ] +  Cos[θ] Derivative[1][ r][θ]))/(-r[θ] Sin[θ] +  Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])]/(1 +  Derivative[1][ y][θ]^2/(-r[θ] Sin[θ] +  Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])^2)^( 3/2), y, θ]`

Second,

```
DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][k[Cos[θ] r[θ]] == 
RealAbs[(-((Derivative[1][
      y][θ] (-Cos[θ] r[θ] - 
       2 Sin[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ] + 
       Cos[θ] (r^′′)[θ]))/(-r[θ] 
Sin[θ] + Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])^2) + (
    y^′′)[θ]/(-r[θ] Sin[θ] + 
    Cos[θ] Derivative[1][
      r][θ]))/(-r[θ] Sin[θ] + 
   Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])]/(1 + 
   Derivative[1][y][θ]^2/(-r[θ] Sin[θ] + 
     Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])^2)^(3/2), 
   y, θ], r, θ,  y[θ] == r[θ]*Sin[θ]] // Simplify
```

> `Inactive[DSolve][ k[Cos[θ] r[θ]] ==  RealAbs[( r[θ]^2 + 2 Derivative[1][r][θ]^2 -  r[θ] ( r^′′)[θ])/(r[θ] Sin[θ] -  Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])^3]/(( r[θ]^2 +  Derivative[1][r][θ]^2)/(r[θ] Sin[θ] -  Cos[θ] Derivative[1][r][θ])^2)^(3/2), r, θ]`

> $k(\cos (\theta ) r(\theta ))=\frac{\left| \frac{r(\theta )^2-r''(\theta ) r(\theta )+2 r'(\theta )^2}{\left(r(\theta ) \sin (\theta )-\cos (\theta ) r'(\theta )\right)^3}\right| }{\left(\frac{r'(\theta )^2+r(\theta )^2}{\left(\sin (\theta ) r(\theta )-\cos (\theta ) r'(\theta )\right)^2}\right)^{3/2}}$